# Objective-c -> Isometric grid

Tags: objective-c, grid, isometric

Sorry, but i do have a question which is a little different from the norm.  I want to make a game display which appears to be isometric, so every cell is:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Rhombus_01.png

in shape.  I am a bit unsure how to do this effectively, though I am currently using a 2D array

```
(M1[5][8] = {{0, 2, 1, 3...},{...}}
```

to relay which images to position where.  My main issue is making sure that the tiles end up where they are supposed to.  Currently i have them 45px high by 60px wide.  I would like to ask if anyone could give me a hand setting things up so that the level screen appears somewaht isometric.  Thank you for you time :)

Answer (score 2):

Cocos2d can support isometric maps.   To get started with Cocos2d, there is nothing better than [Ray Wenderlich's multiple part tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1163/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d)!  It doesn't cover isometric projections, but you'll still need to know the basics of cocos2d.

Note that Cocos2d is open source and, thus, you could study the source to see how it implements isometric projections if you decide to roll your own solution.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This isnt exactly what I was looking for, but it does have some very useful information for me which is vital!  Thank you!!! :-)